# Azure SQL Database roles and access

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

What harm can a user with `GRANT SELECT ON database.dbo.view TO User` access can do? The user can see Security folder in SSMS, roles and can also see master database, roles, etc.? Is there a way we can restrict the user to not see or modify any security roles/groups but can see only a view?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SSMS, a new user will not see the database tables/views without proper roles/permission provided to them but they can see the database objects like Security Users, schema or Roles etc., however they still cannot perform any actions on them if they don't have proper permissions granted to them. As an example if you created a new user and granted a select for a single view, that user will just be able to Select from the view and not able to do anything else on it like altering/deleting the view. Also same user can see the security objects but cannot make any changes on them as well.

We can hide the databases from user in SSMS by using below statement but this is going to hide all the database(even the database in which user has access to see the view).

```
DENY VIEW ANY DATABASE TO <login name>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking sometime and answering the question